# QEMU: What are "serial0" and "parallel0"? How to use them?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

Host and guest both are Archlinux.
Running VM with this command:
`qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -m 2G -nic none -cdrom archlinux.iso`
We have the following options under **View** in **VM window's menubar**:

- VGA
- compatmonitor0
- serial0
- parallel0

I understand first two.
But what are `serial0` and `parallel0`?
What are use cases of them againt the VM?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need them, why use them or even bother asking? :-)

These are ports:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port

The serial (COM) port is often used for debugging.

The parallel port was very popular 20 years ago and used to attach printers. It's basically dead at this moment.

Both ports can be connected to your real PC ports. The com port can be used as a basic console, i.e. you can read and write from it.